# normalizing matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, normalize

I have an rgb image matrix (height*width*3) represented in doubles.
After some manipulations on the matrix, some values went biger then 1 or smaller then 0.
I need to normalize those valuse back to 1 and 0.
Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, just use the indexing by condition. Let's say your matrix is called M.
If you just want to set values bigger than 1 to 1 and smaller than 0 to zero, use:

```
M(M > 1) = 1;
M(M < 0) = 0;
```

However, if you want to proportionally normalize all the values to the interval [0; 1], then you have to do something similar to:

```
mmin = min(M(:));
mmax = max(M(:));
M = (M-mmin) ./ (mmax-mmin); % first subtract mmin to have [0; (mmax-mmin)], then normalize by highest value
```

You have to take account of the case when your matrix M is already in the interval [0; 1] and the normalization is not needed.

Comment: Thanks, indeed it does what i asked. But the result is not good enough so i guess that i need realy to normalize the matrix. the bigst value should be 1, smalest 0 , and everything else betwin proportionaly.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get it right. I've edited my answer. Hope, it's what you wanted.

Comment: @Curdeius: If you want to crop the values in the range [0,1] (your first solution), you can also write it vectorized as: `M = min(max(M,0),1)`

Comment: @Curdeius: Maybe the last action should be `(M = (M-mmin) ./ (mmax-mmin);`)? (instead of .*)

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to see the images you can use

```
imagesc(M);
```

it takes care of the range itself.

If you want to change the values manually and have full control over it,

```
M = M ./ max(M(:));
```

would do the trick if you only have positive values.
To get a full contrast image you might want to:

```
m = m - min(m(:));
m = m ./ max(m(:));
```